# Google Drive API download files from shared drive

Tags: php, download, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client, google-drive-shared-drive

I am trying to download a file from a shared drive via the Google API. I always get the response that the file was not found (code 404).

This does not work even if I have full access (admin) to the folder. The files are created by me. If I have saved them in "My folder", this works without any problems.

I use the export endpoint for Google's own files, to export as PDF: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/export

And for all other files I use the get endpoint:
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/get

I'm working with the Google API PHP Client (v2.15.3):
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/

The Google Drive API is activated in the Google Console. The OAuth 2.0 client ID for web applications is also set up. With all rights that are available with the Google Drive API.

How can I retrieve the files from shared drive?

Here is the code where I am trying to retrieve the file:

```
<?php

    require_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'vendor' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'autoload.php';

    $client = new Google_Client();

    # Todo: need to change
    $client->setAuthConfig( __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'client_secret.json' );
    $client->addScope( Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE );
    $client->setAccessType( 'offline' );

    $protocol   = ( ! empty( $_SERVER[ 'HTTPS' ] ) && $_SERVER[ 'HTTPS' ] !== 'off' || $_SERVER[ 'SERVER_PORT' ] == 443 ) ? "https://" : "http://";
    $currentUrl = $protocol . $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] . $_SERVER[ 'PHP_SELF' ];

    $client->setRedirectUri( $currentUrl );

    if ( ! isset( $_GET[ 'code' ] ) ) {
        $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
        header( 'Location: ' . filter_var( $auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL ) );
        exit;
    }
    else {
        var_dump( $_GET[ 'code' ] );
        var_dump( $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode( $_GET[ 'code' ] ) );

        $_SESSION[ 'access_token' ] = $client->getAccessToken();

        $driveService   = new Google_Service_Drive( $client );
        
        # Todo: need to change
        $google_file_id = 'YOUR_FILE_ID_HERE';

        try {
            $file_metadata = $driveService->files->get( $google_file_id );
            $response      = $driveService->files->get( $google_file_id, array( 'alt' => 'media' ) );
            $content       = $response->getBody()->getContents();

            if ( $file_metadata->getMimeType() && str_starts_with( $file_metadata->getMimeType(), 'application/vnd.google-apps.' ) ) {
                $response  = $driveService->files->export( $google_file_id, 'application/pdf', [ 'alt' => 'media' ] );
                $file_name = $file_metadata->getName() . '.pdf';
            }
            else {
                $response  = $driveService->files->get( $google_file_id, [ 'alt' => 'media', 'supportsAllDrives' => true ] );
                $file_name = $file_metadata->getName();
            }

            file_put_contents( __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file_name, $content );

            echo "Stored!";

        }
        catch ( Exception $e ) {
            echo '<pre>';
            var_export( $e );
            echo '</pre>';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, I think that `supportsAllDrives` is required to be used for retrieving the file metadata and the file content by `files->get`. So, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```php
$client->setAccessToken( $access_token );

$driveService  = new Google_Service_Drive( $client );
$file_metadata = $driveService->files->get( $google_file_id, ['fields' => "name,mimeType", "supportsAllDrives" => true] ); // or ['fields' => "*", "supportsAllDrives" => true]

if ( $file_metadata->getMimeType() && str_starts_with( $file_metadata->getMimeType(), 'application/vnd.google-apps.' ) ) {
    $response  = $driveService->files->export( $google_file_id, 'application/pdf');
    $file_path = $routine_path . $file_metadata->getName() . '.pdf';
}
else {
    $response  = $driveService->files->get( $google_file_id, [ 'alt' => 'media', "supportsAllDrives" => true ] );
    $file_path = $routine_path . $file_metadata->getName();
}

$content = $response->getBody()->getContents();

if ( file_put_contents( $file_path, $content ) ) {
    $file_paths[] = $file_path;
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Method: files.get of Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/get)

Comment: I've added your suggested modification. but without success ... I still get an exception with the 404 code.

Comment: @aswiss Thank you for replying. About `I've added your suggested modification. but without success ... I still get an exception with the 404 code.`, I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, when I tested my proposed script, no error occurred. I apologize for this situation. I think that in this case, it is required to replicate your situation. So, can you provide your whole script reflecting my proposed modification without your private information? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I have updated my question and provide the entire code.

Comment: @aswiss Thank you for replying. I said `can you provide your whole script reflecting my proposed modification without your private information?`. I would like to believe that your updated question reflects my comment. About `Thanks for your support. I have updated my question and provide the entire code.`, when I saw your updated question, I thought that unfortunately, you don't reflect my proposed modifications. I think that this is due to your current issue. Can you reflect on my proposed modifications and test it?

Comment: @aswiss When I tested my proposed script again, I confirmed that the script worked for the shared drive again. I apologize for this situation.

Comment: You are right, sorry! I've copied the code form all classes to make is shareable. I had not seen the "supportsAllDrives" for the file.get endpoint in the else condition. Now it works. Thank you!

Comment: I had to add the opt. parameters to the file.export endoint ([ 'alt' => 'media' ]) ... Otherwise $content will be empty.